# Link a div to a particular section on a different page in HTML

Tags: html

hey I have a new dilemma.....

I have 3 div like 3 boxes and in each div there is an image and some text written and i want that when i click anywhere in any if the box then it will go to the other page e.g. if i am on home page then on clicking on box then it will go to service.html page in the website.

I have done this by

```
<div onClick="document.location='service.html';">
```

and its working.but i want that when user **click on first div** then it **go to service .html and in that particular section** and on second box it will go to another section on service.html and so on.......

To be more clear, **I want to link a div to a particular section to the particular page..**

How can I do this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to add an ID to the elements on the `service.html` page you want to link to, and then include them in your links:

```
<div onClick="window.location.href='service.html#section-1';">Go to Section 1</div>
<div onClick="window.location.href='service.html#section-2';">Go to Section 2</div>
```

P.S. Any reason you're using Javascript instead of regular anchor tags?

Comment: Look at how this link works to link to the answer on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314990/link-a-div-to-a-particular-section-on-a-different-page-in-html/7315010#answers-header

Answer (score 2):

hey i have get ma answer......

```
<div onClick="document.location='service.html#section1_ID';">
<div onClick="document.location='service.html#section2_ID';">
<div onClick="document.location='service.html#section3_ID';">
```

and on that section I have used that particular

```
<div id="section1_ID">bla bla bla</div>
```

and so on.............

Answer (score 1):

Look on below.

```js
// jQuery method
$('.location').bind("click", function() {
  window.location = $(this).data('location');
});

<div class="collection-item location" 
      data-location="service.html#section1_ID" >
   Lorem ipsum, blah
</div>
```