# Link to div not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a site where almost all the different sections are on the home page and i use jQuery scroll to scroll to them when i click the link in the navigation bar

I had to make a different page and i wanted to link those sections to that page too, like when i click about on the other page it takes me to the home page's about div so i used this code for it

```
<a href="./index.html#about">About.</a>
```

It does take me to the about div on the index but that div is on the middle of my screen instead of top

I mean the starting of the div is supposed to be at the top of the screen (just like it is when i navigate to it using a link on the homepage)

Is there any way to fix this?

Edit:

What it looks like when i use the link on the same page:

https://gyazo.com/b51f24e9a13c6f0c4115bc38df34081f

What it looks like when i use the link on the other page:

https://gyazo.com/3724c7486aeef34cc7be5547fb9ffa53

I hope it makes sense

Edit: It works fine in chrome and the issue only occurs in firefox

Comment: Redirect same page and another page?

Comment: The problem occurs when i redirect to a div on the homepage from another page

Comment: Can you provide fiddle.... bcoz its bit confusing.

Comment: Or the html code of the div.

Comment: <a href="index.htm#about">Sutton</a> - 
In the document index.htm, the section on About would contain an id with that name - 

<h2 id="about">about</h2>
<p>Info  </p>

Comment: @Uzer. I just updated my answer check once.

Comment: It does
It works fine when i use the link to navigate to the about div from the same page

Answer (score 1):

I created a plnkr< https://plnkr.co/edit/jmKjbwmKCvKGfz3QuExx?p=preview > !#div2 will be on top after clicking the hyperlink on new.html!

```
<a href="index.html#div2">
```

Comment: I have the same thing on my page and it works in chrome but not in firefox

Comment: I created this on firefox and it is working fine with my example!

Comment: I think it's because there is nothing above the div

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.location place of anchor tag.

```
 <div id="section1_ID">Click Me</div>
 <div id="section1_ID">Click Me</div>
 <div id="section1_ID">Click Me</div>
```

Referral link.

```
<div onClick="document.location='service.html#section1_ID';">
<div onClick="document.location='service.html#section2_ID';">
<div onClick="document.location='service.html#section3_ID';">
```

For more clearification.
[Link a div to a particular section on a different page in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314990/link-a-div-to-a-particular-section-on-a-different-page-in-html/7315010#answers-header)

Comment: It does the same thing
I added a few pictures in the first post, i hope it explains my issue better

Answer (score 0):

Is there enough content after this About section. If isn't then it won't appear on the top.

What does the other end of the anchor look like? It should go e.g. like this:

```
<div id="about">...</div>
```

Comment: There is
It works like it's supposed to when i navigate to it using the link on the same page

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for this can be that your page does not have enough height to move **about** to the top of the screen. To overcome this, you can add a `min-height` to the page or the `div`.

Another reason can be that a part of the page is populating after page load (for example - images) which is increasing the height of the page. So, then the page is loaded about shows at the correct place, but when you link it from another page, it does not get enough time to populate that part of the page. To solve this, you can make that part of the page of fixed height in CSS.

I can give you code solution if you share code for your page.

Comment: It works fine when i navigate to the div with the link on the same page

Comment: if you can share code of the page, i would be able to help you more